# Problems deleting first record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

When I try to delete the first record from a table of added records I get this error :

RUN-TIME ERROR '3021' NO CURRENT RECORD

This only happens when I try to delete the first record. When I try to delete the second or third my code works fine:

```
Me.Labour_subform.Form.Recordset.Delete 

Me.Labour_subform.Form.Recordset.MoveNext
```

This is my code for the on_click of a button. Dose anyone know how to correct this ?

Comment: `If Recordset.Count > 0 then ` ? how about movefirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always check for EOF then move to the first record when I am dealing with recordsets.

```
If not Me.Labour_subform.Form.Recordset.EOF then
     Me.Labour_subform.Form.Recordset.MoveFirst
     'Then delete or do whatever
end if
```